# xml.tag! in Ruby on Rails 3 linking

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, hyperlink, custom-tag

I am trying to create an xml.builder file that puts links into cells that I am then using a javascript library to render into a table.

Basically I'd like to make the following item a link.

```
xml.tag!("cell", person.name)
```

something like this.

```
xml.tag!("cell", person_path(@person))
```

Though I know this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [XmlMarkup](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder/blob/master/lib/builder/xmlmarkup.rb) class:

```
xml.a(person.name, 'href' => person_path(@person) )
```

Use `.tag` with a tag name in parentheses and attributes in curly braces to create a custom tag:

```
xml.tag!("cell"){xml.a(person.name, 'href' => person_path(@person) )}
```

**References**

- [Builder Gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/builder)

Comment: I need to maintain the custom tag "cell" how do I combine this class with the .tag! ?

Comment: xml.tag!("cell"){xml.a(person.name, 'href' => person_path(@person) )}